# Symfony: Turning a SQL query into a correct Doctrine QueryBuilder Instance

Tags: doctrine-orm

I need a working query builder in symfony for the following SQL:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(ii.invoice_id) FROM invoice WHERE invoice_number = i.invoice_number) as c, 
i.id as invoice_id, i.invoice_number, ii.logistician_id FROM invoice i
LEFT JOIN incoming_invoice ii ON i.id = ii.invoice_id
GROUP BY invoice_id
HAVING c < 2;
```

Im testing since yesterday but i do not get it working.

```
public function findAllWithoutIncomingInvoice(): array
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->select('i, ii, COUNT(ii.invoice_id) FROM invoice WHERE invoice_number = i.invoice_number) as c')
        ->leftJoin('i.incomingInvoices', 'ii')
        ->groupBy('i.id')
        ->having('c < 2')
        ->setMaxResults(15)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 40 near 'invoice WHERE': Error: Class 'invoice' is not defined.

Comment: Can you also edit your post with the error you're getting?..

Comment: I'm not getting that part `(SELECT COUNT(ii.invoice_id) FROM invoice WHERE invoice_number = i.invoice_number)`, why do you select a count here ? Also, can you add your classes (invoice, incoming invoice) to your question please ?

Comment: @Preciel  Each invoice (i) can have multiple incoming_invoice (ii) entries. But i need only which have less than 2 entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should properly name your aliases, it make it easier to read back your code.
Also, make sure you use double quote to write your DQL, as Doctrine will require simple quote around text values

As for your answer, it should be something close to this :

```php
public function findAllWithoutIncomingInvoice(): array {
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select("invoice")
       ->from(Invoice::class, "invoice")
       ->join("invoice.incomingInvoice", "incomingInvoice")
       ->groupBy("invoice.id")
       ->having("COUNT(incomingInvoice.id) < 2");

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```